# Why does the Ubuntu Software Center use Python 2?

Tags: xubuntu, python-2.7, cleanup

The Ubuntu Software Center is described as,

> Utility for browsing, installing, and removing software
>    Ubuntu Software Center lets you browse and install thousands of
>    free and paid applications available for Ubuntu. You can view available
>    software by category, or search quickly by name or description.
>    You can also examine the software already installed, and remove items
>    you no longer need. To install or remove software using USC, you need administrator access on the computer.

I'm wanting to remove Python 2. If this is the a core gui-distro utility, why is it on Python 2 (which is EOL in 1 year 1 month), why would my distro ship this?

```
Depends: python:any (>= 2.7)
iso-codes
app-install-data (>= 0.4.0)
aptdaemon (>= 0.40)
software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
humanity-icon-theme, gir1.2-glib-2.0 (>= 1.31)
gir1.2-gtk-3.0
gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 (>= 3.1.5)
gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
gvfs-backends
python-gi (>= 3.4.0-1ubuntu0.1)
python-gi-cairo
python-xapian
python-apt (>= 0.8.3ubuntu4)
python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40)
python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
python-dbus
python-defer
python-lxml
policykit-1
policykit-1-gnome | policykit-1-kde
python-xdg
ubuntu-sso-client
python-piston-mini-client (>= 0.1+bzr29)
oneconf (>= 0.2.6)
python-oneconf (>= 0.3) | oneconf (
```

---

This question is about why a piece of software is holding back Python 2 from autoremove and has **nothing** do to with installing software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @N0rbert could you explain how this is a duplicate of that?

Comment: It is duplicate because you are trying to find GUI software manager to install software and you have ended with `software-center` application.

Comment: No. I'm not. I was trying to remove Python 2.

Comment: You should not remove python2 as it is core system-wide component.

Comment: It's actually not, which is I why asking this question. Go read something.

Comment: It says any Python later than or equal to 2.7... are you sure it needs Python 2?

Comment: @Zanna yes, because `python` (the metapackage) is for Python 2. `Depends: python2.7 (>= 2.7.15-1~), libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.15-3), python2 (= 2.7.15-3)
`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu dropped the software center in 16.04, and it's been [unmaintained since 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center). In some versions, like Ubuntu it was replaced with `gnome-software`. However, in Xubuntu not requiring Gnome it simply removed the dependency on the `software-center` and left it hanging. Your distro probably has been distupgraded since pre-16.04.

Simply remove it yourself,

```
sudo apt-get --purge --yes remove software-center
sudo apt-get autoremove # remove all things it required.
```

Optionally, if you want a gui to install packages install `software-center`.